# How to store random number in usigned char variable in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, srand

I am wanting to fill a unsigned char 2d array with random 8 bit hex numbers using rand(). But I am getting weird results(seen below) when I try to save them in my array. It works fine if I change the 2d array to an int array, but I really wanna keep unsigned char so I know only numbers that are 8 bit can be saved into each index. Here is the code I was testing on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    unsigned char key[4][4];

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            key[x][y] = (rand() % 256);
            cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << key[x][y] << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Is there any solution to this? Or is there a better way to fill my 2d array with random 8bit numbers?

To clarify weird results, this is what I get:

```
0┘ | 0☻ | 0| | 0┌ |
0L | 0ä | 0⌐ | 0ä |
0☺ | 0î | 0X | 0Y |
0▬ | 0╧ | 0@ | 0╩ |
```

Comment: Can you define "weird results" in more technical terms?

Comment: What sort of weird results? Printed characters? Sometimes just writing down what you receive and what you expect allows you to see and fix the discrepancy.

Comment: @tadman@user4581301
I added the results in an edit, sorry for the confusion. I am expecting hex numbers, so ex (12, 5F, 3C, 74, etc)

Comment: Like this `cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (unsigned)key[x][y] << " | ";` The cast makes sure that the chars get printed as integers (instead of chars) which is presumably what you want.

Comment: Printed characters. It annoys the <expletive deleted> out of me sometimes, but  `unsigned char` is still a character type and `<<` treats it as a character and not a number.

Comment: That output is being interpreted as `char*` which it is not. Try casting to `int` before display.

Comment: @john@tadman Thank you both, both fix my problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Been there. To me, `uint8_t` and `int8_t` are worse.

Comment: Those are the little devils.  It's about 50-50 whether or not I remember the suckers are not really numbers before I print them. Never have this problem in C, though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way the values are being stored. The problem is in how they are being displayed. `char` types are interpreted as character code points, which is why you're seeing weird characters. So change them to a non-`char` type, typically by casting to `unsigned` or, more simply, displaying `+key[x][y]`; the `+` makes that an arithmetic expression, and values in an arithmetic expression are converted to `int` or `unsigned int` if their types are smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Need to cast key[x][y] as int or unsigned, for example:

```
cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (unsigned)key[x][y] << " | ";
```

or

```
cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << int(key[x][y]) << " | ";
```

As answered by John and Tadman

Comment: You can also use a unary operator: `cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << +key[x][y] << " | ";`

Comment: This answer should explain why the original code doesn't work as expected, and why this change fixes the problem.